# Printing a value makes the program work?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

bool numar(unsigned long long n)
{
    return (n > 99) && ((n % 100) == 25);
}

int main()
{
    freopen("numere.in", "r", stdin);
    freopen("numere.out", "w", stdout);

    int cnt = 0;

    unsigned long long n, a, Nblabla, N;

    while (scanf("%d", &n) == 1)
    {
        if (numar(n))
        {
            a = (n - 25) / 100;

            cout << a; // This son of a *****.

            for (N = 1; true; N++)
            {
                Nblabla = N * (N + 1);

                if (Nblabla > a)
                    break;
                else if (Nblabla == a)
                {
                    cnt++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    printf("%d", cnt);

    return 0;
}
```

Simply, if I comment that line (`cout << a;`), the program stops working. If I leave it there, it works.
I'm using Code::Blocks, GNU GCC.

This just checks if a number is the square of a number that ends with the digit `5`. (Base 10) (I am not allowed to use square roots)

Before asking, no, this isn't homework. This is my submission to a subject of an online contest.

Can anyone tell me why is this happening?

Comment: First of all, what do you mean by "stops working"? Please be more precise. Second, harmless printing altering program behaviour is a sign of UB. Do you compile with `-Wall` ?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I just use the default compiler settings in Code::Blocks. I only use C/C++ for school and contests, not for anything personal, so I didn't fiddle with the settings. **Edit**: By "stops working" I mean that it takes 3 seconds to check 5 numbers (2-4 digits) and it prints 0 in the end (`printf("%d", cnt);`).

Comment: Well, fiddle with it. `warning: format ‘%d’ expects type ‘int*’, but argument 2 has type ‘long long unsigned int*’` - this alone should be enough reason to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `%d` format, `scanf` will try to read a pointer to `int`. But `&n` is a pointer to `unsigned long long`. This leads to an undefined behavior, which could be the reason of your strange result.

The right format is `%llu`.

Comment: Ah shi--... I forgot to change that when I changed from `int` to `unsigned long long`... Anyway, what does that have to do with printing `a`? **Edit**: Ah, undefined behavior... Damn it.

Comment: @Vercas: First of all, because it is an undefined behavior, anything can happen, including "Works only when printing!". However, I guess the other bits of `n` not filled with `scanf` remain uinitialized in your implementation. On my machine, it doesn't work either with `std::cout` call.